# Drawing circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Choose some set of $7$ points $x_1, \dots, x_7$. Find the minimum number of lines/circles that can pass through at least 3 of the 7 points

Comment: A line is determined by $2$ points, so there are only $\binom72$ possibilities to begin with.  Unfortunately, this only reduces it to $C+L\leq 11$.

Comment: $L=7$ is impossible because that is the Fano plane configuration which you can't draw on the plane with straight lines alone, but that can achieve $C+L=9$ (vertices of an equilateral triangle, mid-points of the sides and the centroid has 6 lines, plus the three circles with each side as diameter).

Comment: @user10354138 interesting–so the statement of the problem was wrong. I will change it to "find the minimum value of $C+L$."

Answer (score 2):

Let's collect up what we know

- $L\leq 7$: each line is determined by two points.  Each triple of collinear points uses up 3 pairs of points, so $L\leq\binom{7}{2}/3=7$.
- $L=7$ is impossible --- each point lies on three of the 7 lines and each of the 7 lines has three points needs the extra circle in the Fano plane configuration.
- $C+L\leq 11$
- $\max(C+L)\geq 9$ by the equilateral triangle + medians +three circles example.
- $4C+L\leq 21$.
- There are no feasible nonnegative integer solutions to $C+L\geq 10$, $4C+L\leq 21$, $L\leq 6$, since this means $3C\leq 11$, so $C\leq 3$ and hence $L\geq 7$.

So the optimal bound is $C+L\leq 9$.

Comment: How do we see $4C+L\leq21$?

Comment: @saulspatz it is equivilant to $L\leq {7\choose 2}-4C$.

Comment: @JimmyJohn Since you edited your question to remove your work, this isn't explained anywhere.  I feel strongly that you should put your work back in the question.